# How google allo recognise date or time in the message to create an event?

Tags: java, android, datetime, nlp

I want to parse message and identify if it contains day/date/time to create a event based on time in the message. I have checked jchronic, natty, Sutime that does nlp but not able to integrate with android app. I have seen Google allo also recognise text but not too complex sentence. Is google provides any api to identify the date/time from natural language? if not what step I can begin with for my own implementation in java?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes they do this with API not any library in android (this is the reason you can't do it offline).

The NLP parser along with the message it takes your calendar too and pushes to Google Calendar. The API are available but the level of use available to us is not that much. Here is the link for [GOOGLE CLOUD NATURAL LANGUAGE API](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/)